# Why android realm's greaterThan not support String, while comon sql support it, how can I make greaterThan method support String parameter?

Tags: android, database, realm

I store date in string in realm, now I need to query future days which need to use greater Than method.

Comment: `I store date in string in realm` you should be storing date as **Date**

Comment: Yes, I agree. but I am not the developing team leader... You know some issue is caused by the not smart leader. and Now I had adding another date field in my local realm table to complete the compare task.